# A connected deformation retract implies connectedness of the bigger space?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am trying to show that if A is a deformation retract of X and A is connected, then X is connected.
I am trying to prove by contradiction.
Can anyone give me some hint?

Answer (score 1):

Let $H : X \times [0,1] \to X$ be a deformation retraction from $X$ to $A$, and so $H$ is a continuous function such that $H(x,0)=x$ and $H(x,1) \in A$ for all $x \in X$ (maybe $H$ satisfies even stronger properties, but this is all one should need).

It follows that for each $x \in X$ there is a connected subset $P_x \subset X$ such that $x \in P_x$ and $P_x \cap A \ne \emptyset$, namely $P_x = \{H(x,t) \,|\, t \in [0,1]\}$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Complex coefficients.