# show that discrete space of $X$ is contractible if have one point.

Tags: algebraic-topology

please answer this

show that discrete space of $X$ is contractible if  have one point.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One direction is trivial.

If $X$ were contractible, then $id \cong c_{x_1}$, where $id$ is identity, and $c_{x_1}$ is a constant map on an arbitrary point. However, let $x_2 \in X$ be any other point. For any map
$F:X  \times [0,1] \to X$ such that $F(x_2,0)=x_2$ and $F(x_2,1)=x_1$, we have a problem since $x_2 \times [0,1]$ is connected...

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2216401/a-connected-deformation-retract-implies-connectedness-of-the-bigger-space) is a slight generalization of this statement, from a question asked last night.